# c# how to remove selected item from datagrid using button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have daragrid and i wanna detele selected row using button. How can i do it? thanks

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<User>(FormOfAddData.MyList);
```

Comment: FYI, all the downvotes are due to the lack of perceived work.  If you need help, show some pseudo Unit Testing

Answer (score 2):

Bind your data onto an observable collection. And just remove it from your collection.

```
var myData = new ObservableCollection<User>(FormOfAddData.MyList);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = myData;

private void OnButtonClick(){
  User user = dataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
  if(user != null){
    myData.Remove(user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (datagrid1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    datagrid1.Items.Remove((BindingData)datagrid1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: You can't remove an item the Items collection when you have set the ItemsSource property.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` as suggested by @Tobias Theel:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<User>(FormOfAddData.MyList);
```

..you can remove the selected item from the source collection as follows.

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click_1" />
```

**Code:**

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    User user = dataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
    if (user != null)
    {
        IList<User> users = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<User>;
        if (users != null)
            users.Remove(user);
    }
}
```

If you keep using a `List<User>`, you will have to reset the `ItemsSource` property:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    User user = dataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
    if (user != null)
    {
        IList<User> users = dataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<User>;
        if (users != null)
            users.Remove(user);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like the following;

```
 private void DeleteSelectedRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.SelectedRows)
     {
         dataGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
     }
 }
```